# Changes Aren't Saved After Shut Down - Ubuntu 16.10 Live USB

Tags: boot, usb, live-usb, shutdown

I want to use Ubuntu 16.10 from my 8gb usb pen-drive. I've noticed that whenever I make any changes to it they all get reverted after shut down.

All the files I have downloaded, documents, etc, get automatically deleted.

Everything else is working completely fine except no changes are saved.

Comment: The answers on the duplicated page, (that predate this question), are no longer valid, the page is close to four years old, persistent partitions no longer work with syslinux installs such as SDC, UNetbootin,Rufus etc, The duplicate post police are showing a lack of knowledge about persistent installs. The duplicated question asks about persistent installs, this question does not rule out a Full install for an answer.

Comment: And furthermore, persistence with 13.04 is quite different than with 16.10, heck you can't even make a casper-rw partition on a SDC or Rufus pendrive anymore.

Comment: Do the DPP even read both questions? the duplicated post is asking about persistence on a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

You can either do a Full install to pendrive, as you would to internal drive or do a Persistent install.
If a Full install, it is recommended to first disable the internal drive.
A persistent install is more compact and will fit on a 2GB or larger drive.

**Startup Disk Creator** that comes with Ubuntu no longer does persistent installs.

**Unetbootin** will do persistent installs and has a Linux version and a Windows version. Persistence is limited to 4GB with UNetbootin as it uses a FAT32 file system.

I prefer **mkusb**, a Linux only installer.
Mkusb makes several partitions, a boot partition, a read only ISO9660 OS partition, a casper-rw persistent partition, (without the 4GB limit) and a NTFS data partition that can be accessed by both Windows and Linux.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb